# How to overwrite variables from a parent class in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance

I am currently struggling with a problem where one has the following setup:

```
class Model
{
    public $tableConnection = null;

    ....
}
```

Now there is a class which inherits *Model.*

```
class NewModel extends Model
{
    public $tableConnection = array("belongsTo" => "otherModel");

    ...
}
```

What I would like to acchieve is to define *tableConnection* just by putting a definition into the child class (*NewModel)* in order to overwrite the original variable within the class *Model*.

*NewModel* should be as simple as possible without additional methods or functions, instead *Model* can include anything useful. Someone maybe recognized a similarity to the CakePHP Framework. I am trying to understand how those things can be acchieved. And maybe there is some PHP wizzard out there who knows how to deal with this :-)

Comment: You overwrite properties from parent classes exactly like this. What's your question? `$foo = new NewModel(); var_dump($foo->tableConnection);`

Comment: Well it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Are you actually creating an instance of `NewModel`? Where are you fetching this value? [The code you've posted would work fine.](https://eval.in/509290)

Comment: Side note: A model must not be a class. Model is an abstraction layer that contain services. While a service itself is a bridge between domain objects and data mappers. You seem to call data mapper as "model"

Comment: You are doing it correctly. This works. https://gist.github.com/PEMapModder/b3d46f1220d70c3ecbc5

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this. I will try and see why it is not working with my setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working, please check here:-

```
<?php

class Model
{
    public $tableConnection = null;
}
class NewModel extends Model
{
    public $tableConnection = array("belongsTo" => "otherModel");
}
$obj = new NewModel();
print_r($obj->tableConnection);
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/509293